# For any non-empty subset $A$ of real numbers define $f_A : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ by, $f_A(x)= \inf \{ |x-y| : y \in A \}$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, uniform-continuity

> For any non-empty subset $A$ of real numbers define $f_A : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ by, $$f_A(x)= \inf \{ |x-y| : y \in A \}$$

> Let, $A,B$ be disjoint non-empty sets of real numbers such that $f_A(x)+ f_B(x) \gt 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Define a function $g : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, $$g(x) = \frac{f_A(x)}{f_A(x)+ f_B(x)}$$
> Then,

> $(i)$ why $g$ is continuous?

> $(ii)$ give an example of two disjoint non-empty subsets of real numbers $A,B$, such that $f_A(x)+ f_B(x) \gt 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and for which $g$ is not uniformly continuous.

I've proved that the function $f_A(x), f_B(x)$ are continuous. So their sum is also continuous and hence $g$ being the quotient of two continuous functions whose denominator is always positive, is continuous.

For the second part I've thought of closed disjoint sets $A,B$. For example I thought of $A = \{0\}$ and $B = \{-1\}$. Then the function $g$ becomes $$g(x) = \frac {|x|}{|x|+|x+1|}$$

But I can't check if it's not uniformly continuous. Plotting it I found that there's no steep ascent or descent so it must be uniformly continuous.

Can anyone please help me with the part two??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $A=\{1, 2, 3, 4, ...\}$. Let $B=\{1+\frac 12, 2+\frac 13, 3+\frac 14, 4+\frac 15, ...\}$.

Thus for any $\epsilon$ we can find $a_i\in A$, $b_i \in B$ so that $|a_i-b_i|<\epsilon$. Thus $g(a_i)=0$, $g(b_i)=1$.

Comment: Can you please elaborate more. I can't understand anything.

Comment: We simplified the example a little.

Comment: Okay so for $\epsilon = \frac{1}{2}$ and for any $\delta \gt 0$ we can always find two points $a_i,b_i$ with $|a_i - b_i| \lt \delta$ but $|g(a_i) -g(b_i)| = 1$ which is not less than $\epsilon = \frac{1}{2}$. Hence it is not uniformly continuous. Did I get it correctly?